# How to create nginx alias to wordpress plugins directory

Tags: wordpress, nginx, alias, symlink

I am running wordpress on nginx and trying to create an alias that will point to a plugin directory where I have written some of my own plugins that I have versioned under git. Currently I am using unix symlinks to do the job however I would prefer to do this (if possible) with nginx and make my transition from dev to prod more seamless. I cannot seem to get the configuration correct. I have included my directory structure and nginx config below. Any help would be appreciated - Thanks!

**WP Install (*Shows symlinks which I would like to replace with nginx alias*)**

```
/home/foobar/www/wordpress
---- /wp-content/plugins
-------- /hello-dolly/
-------- /akismet/
-------- mycustom1 -> /home/foobar/myplugins/mycustom1/
-------- mycustom2 -> /home/foobar/myplugins/mycustom1/
```

**My custom plugins (*versioned under git*)**

```
/home/foobar/myplugins
---- /mycustom1/
---- /mycustom2/
```

**Nginx Configuration**

```
server {

    listen       80;

    server_name foobar.com;
    root    /home/foobar/www/wordpress;
    index   index.php;

    autoindex    off;   

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;        
    }

    location /wp-content/plugins/myplugin {
        alias /home/foobar/myplugins/mycustom1/;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 4K;
        fastcgi_buffers 64 4k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        include  /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param WP_ROOT $document_root;
    }

}
```